# Handling thousands of custom routes from a database in Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, nuxtjs3

I have a Nuxt JS (v3) application with thousands of custom routes, many pointing to the same pages, but at the domain root.

e.g /some-product-name-one, /a-secondary-product-name, /some-category-name, /some-static-page.

So in this case, the slug can be anything at domain root level, which is why i must fetch it from my database to assert which component is to be used.

What i've done is fetch all the routes (about 27.000) from my Database via. an API on build in my `app/router.options.ts` so it looks like so:

```
import type { RouterOptions } from '@nuxt/schema'

export default <RouterOptions> {
    routes: (_routes) => [
        {
            name: 'product_some-product-name-one',
            path: '/some-product-name-one',
            component: () => import('~/pages/product.vue'),
            props: {
                id: '2421'
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'category_some-category-name',
            path: '/some-category-name',
            component: () => import('~/pages/category.vue'),
            props: {
                id: '45'
            }
        },
        {...}
    ]
}
```

Now, the build time was 10 minutes and the application is extremely slow. Navigating to the website timed out.

How can i fetch routes from my database in Nuxt.js and send the user to the correct component?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than baking all of the routes individually into the router, you might want to use a [dynamic route](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/file-system-routing/#dynamic-routes) such as `_id.vue` and handle the varying parameter within the component.

Comment: I thought of that, but wouldn't it make it impossible for me to use Layouts, NuxtPage etc.?

Comment: Ideally, the layout structure should be reflected in the url structure (so that it's possible to know the desired layout without querying the database). If you want to keep everything at the root level, you might be able to use a regex to extract this information from the slug.

Comment: Otherwise if you want to do even more custom routing that doesn't gel with Nuxt's default approach, the answer here might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62452902/nuxt-js-root-routing-and-root-level-slugs-for-multiple-resources?rq=1

Comment: I get the point, but i'm re-making an existing application, and to avoid losing the SEO-structure it's not possible to use regex nor the built in routing.
In the existing application (Purely PHP), we simply query the database with the slug - and it returns which controller to use and thus which views to show. I'm looking for the same kind of approach in Nuxt